# How can i display XML data in a HTML table

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Thanks for suggestion given in 
[search dataset from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327734/search-dataset-from-xml-file)
to use Xpath instead of dataset as in my previous post. I've successfully filtered my xml data (see previous post) using xpath but now I need to display data in a table. How do I do this? I would need to display certain values. How can I choose the nodes I want and display them?

```
    Dim xdoc As New XPathDocument(xt)
    Dim nav As XPathNavigator = xdoc.CreateNavigator()

    Dim expr As XPathExpression = nav.Compile("pf:CONTRACTS/pf:CONTRACT[contains(pf:KEYWORDS,'" word "')]")

    Dim tr As String = Nothing
    Dim namespaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable)
    namespaceManager.AddNamespace("pf", "http://namespace.co.uk/")
    expr.SetContext(namespaceManager)
    Dim nodes As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(expr)

      While nodes.MoveNext()
     'I would need to have "Contact ID", "Contract Name", etc.        
        tr += "<tr><td>" & nodes.Current.Value & "</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>"
    End While
            Dim th As String = "<th>Commodity</th><th>Name</th><th>Supplier</th><th>Name</th>"
    div1.InnerHtml = ("<table class='datatable1'>" & th) + tr & "</table>"
```

Comment: Also, you might want to re-think your entire approach. Creating output HTML via string concatenation in ASP.NET is wrong on so many levels...

Comment: parse the xml as an xdocument/ xdocument then use xslt to do the transform - have a read on xsl, I am very positive you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT to transform XML to any other XML (including HTML).